# Do we have enough knowledge for an alien John Hammond to resurrect our species from scratch?

Tags: biology

Humanity was doomed. The sun was going nova, the Earth's core was stopping, and the Moon was falling down all at once. All counter-measures failed. But the brightest minds came together and built a database, containing all of human scientific knowledge as it exists in 2022 AD (the last time anyone had time to do research), and a vast library on culture and arts. They put this gigantic Wikipedia on drives that preserve data indefinitely, made a hundred copies, and put them in rockets that got sent out into space in random directions.

Hundreds of years later, an alien race finds one of these databases (but not Earth). This species has construction capabilities beyond our wildest dreams; 3D-printing something one atom at a time is what their toddlers do in pre-school. Basically, if one can adequately describe it, they can make it. I will call this species the Hammonds.

However, the Hammonds have an entirely different physiology. They are beings of pure energy and don't even have anything resembling DNA. They translated the database, are very curious about humanity, and they wished that humans still existed.

That brings us to the question this is all about: **do we have the scientific knowledge for someone with infinite construction capabilities to resurrect the human species?**

The Hammonds must construct an ovum and a sperm to perfection (which they can, if we can describe it to perfection). Then they need an artificial womb. They supply the fertilised egg with proper nutrients and let it grow into a new human. Once they got this process working, they can keep going but using different DNA, and finally get a human species.

They need to do that based on our present-day knowledge. So we have documented what eggs are, how they work. We have sequenced genomes of many people, so the new species won't die from inbreeding. [Even the microbiota living in our innards have been sequenced.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Microbiome_Project)

Is anything missing that the Hammonds cannot solve with simple trial and error? Could we see humanity resurrected based on our current scientific knowledge?

Comment: Are we assuming that he has knowledge of every genomic sequence for every human being? And does a human body include the exact length of hair, the tiniest speck of dust, etc.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude the Hammonds have every scientific knowledge about humanity that we do. Every single human genome we ever sequenced got put on that database. I'm not sure what you mean by hair length; the goal is to construct a fertilised ovum and let it grow into a new human, who would have different hair length at different ages.

Comment: a human does not consist of only a single dna sequence. we are more like a colony of thousands of different organisms and we need most of them to survive. even inside the cell we have mitrochondrial dna as well.

Comment: DNA is commentless spaghetti code that makes obscure, perplexing, and undocumented assumptions about the hardware its running on and the environment that hardware is in.

Comment: @notovny that's actually pretty enlightening

Comment: Technically, human DNA contains blueprints for the construction of a ribosome. Good luck finding that though, or understanding how to build one once you've found it. That is the absolute minimum machinery needed to utilize the DNA to construct the rest of the cellular machinery for an ovum I believe. There might be a much simpler description of it as a sequence of proteins out there, but I have no idea if such things could be fabricated even with atomic deposition. Proteins *fold* even while they're being chained together from aminos.

Comment: @notovny Just because you can't read the comments doesn't mean they're not there. It's in the junk DNA. /\*I can't even remember how this works, don't mess with it. - god/\* And then 30,000 base pairs later /\* This doesn't seem to do anything, getting rid of it. - evolution/\* . Maybe you have a hard time with it because they wrote it all in Enochian.

Comment: Sure they do, and then we, the human virii, procreate and introduce conflict and war into their staid pacifistic lives.

Comment: What do you mean by resurrecting humanity? Are we talking about biological species only or do we need to resurrect social structures, culture, and so on? Also, what is your stance regarding reductionism? I.e. can a human be fully reduced to biology or not?

Comment: @Otkin The question is only about the biological resurrection. Whether a test tube person can become true human with only Wikipedia knowledge is something I shall leave open to interpretation :) But, given how unanimous the verdict on the biological component is, I think I might as well accept an answer sooner than I usually do.

Comment: I don't think copying exactly 1:1 is important. The humans created by John Hammond don't need to be *exactly* equal. The Earth photographs should resemble the result closely, languages and writing are copied. The planet should be plausible, the history of Earth should be a plausible history to teach in schools, as "our" history. No one of the old bunch has survived to check things anyway.

Comment: Given that a) we still don't know how to create life from constituent parts in a lab without already existing life to spawn it from and b) there is a vast amount we don't actually know about interactions between things like our microbiome and ourselves (evidenced by the fact we keep discovering more), I would think that it would be extremely difficult and even if moderately successful, unlikely to be particularly healthy.

Comment: @KeizerHarm I think that the answers do not consider enough the capabilities of the aliens. Hammonds are much higher than us technologically and should have a much better understanding of the universe and various processes in the universe. It might be enough to fill the gaps in our knowledge about humans and carbon-based life in general. How much Hammonds can figure out is up to you, the author. Our incomplete knowledge does not have to be a limitation if you do not want it to be.

Comment: @Otkin A good story is a reflection of humanity, not just of the author's fantasy world. To figure out the connection with real life is the entire reason why I come to this site.

Comment: @KeizerHarm I agree. But at the same time, I frequently get a feeling that the WB.SE reflects people's attitudes and beliefs rather than real life.

Comment: @Otkin Definitely, but when I ask about the plausibility of an idea, people's attitudes and beliefs are also valid input. Even if I think they are factually wrong, such a near-consensus indicates that whatever I write may not be properly believed/appreciated if I do not elaborate on it more than I do within a WB.SE question body, or hedge the scenario with notes like the resurrected humans not becoming perfect replicas. Your input is similarly appreciated: the more perspectives the better.

Comment: @KeizerHarm I do not argue that attitudes and beliefs are useless. They are, especially when it comes to suspension of disbelief. It is just, I am not sure how the WB.SE is representative of more general audiences. We do not need to argue about this. It is just some casual thoughts I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently we don't have enough knowledge for this. We know the full genome sequence of several human beings, but we are lacking the knowledge of some crucial steps about how from this sequence becomes a full functioning human cell, let alone a human being. The genome isn't made up of just functioning genes, but a lot of other non transcribing or non translating elements, we don't know the function of all of them currently. The genes itself can produce multiple different variants depending on RNA-slicing, resulting in different proteins. We are lacking knowledge about protein folding as well, and no living organism can function without proper 3D protein structure. And this is only one cell! We don't have enough information about cell maturation, epigenetics, cell-cell interactions, etc., all of this is essential for a complex organism.

Our understanding of genomics today is enough to recreate the genome of the smallest single cell organisms, but we're far from synthetic eukaryotes.
The Hammonds could probably fill the gaps by trial and error, but that would be like a synthetic evolution and would probably result in something different from humans.

We also need consider that some of our current published experimental results are false or not accurate enough. The Hammonds better be great in meta-analysis if they want to use our knowledge!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is knowing the function of every gene really necessary in order to 3D-print a human ovum and let nature run its course? Similarly, while we can't fold proteins, the cell itself can - so why do those things manually?

Comment: About the protein folding: the cell itself uses other proteins (and phospholipids, etc.) to guide and correct the folding process, it isn't just simply the lowest energy conformation, These guides and correctors (called chaperons) also need to be folded properly, so catch 22. Similarly, you need to have proteins for gene expression (transcription, splicing, translation, post-translational modifications...) and they also need to be in the proper conformation

Comment: About the genes: you probably don't need to know the function of each and every 20000 genes of the genome, but you need to know a lot of them. The problem is, the genome in itself isn't enough to create a living organism, you need to have a whole lot of already existing apparatus for the cell to live which "manages" the genome and you need to know the parts and functions of this apparatus. A bad analogy, but if you have a pdf copy of a cookbook, that doesn't mean that you can automatically create a factory printing cookbooks.

Comment: Just look at ribosomes. In eukaryotes, four rRNAs and over 200 proteins are involved in the assembly process of a molecular machine that not just reads a mRNA strand and assembles a protein, but also regulates that assembly process, influences the protein folding, binds to membranes the protein needs to be secreted through, etc. This isn't all fully understood, and it's just dealing with the process of making proteins from mRNA.

Comment: Include even just one frozen human cell, and the dataset is complete. But yes, *just* the dna is not enough, because a lot of our info is not in the DNA of the nucleus. You also need the structure and encoding of the cellular organelles, especially the mitochondria to make a working human body.

Answer (score 10):

> Is anything missing that the Hammonds cannot solve with simple trial and error?

Well, yes. This is almost literally a chicken-and-egg problem. Even if you have the complete DNA sequence for a chicken, you cannot build a chicken from it unless you already have the appropriate construction tools for chicken manufacture, eg. an egg.

Whilst people have managed to assembly viruses from scratch in the past, they're many, *many* orders of magnitude simpler than an egg. Unless it were possible to obtain human eggs, or at least the eggs of something *very* similar, it wouldn't even be possible to create a zygote capable of dividing. Your aliens won't even get to the next nigh-on insurmountable problem of not having a womb for the growing embryo to implant in.

Jurassic Park handwaved this by modifying existing species to produce the first set of new dinosaurs. Your aliens probably don't even have access to so much as a prokaryote (after a few hundred years in interstellar space, those rockets are likely to be pretty sterile even if they were filthy at launch).

> Could we see humanity resurrected

I'd say "humanity" is "civilization", or at least "society". Even if they could replicate humans, without other humans to socialize them what you'll end up with is something rather different from what we see today. They'd be much more alien than us.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, while we may have the full gene sequence of humans, and may be able to specify the molecular structure of an egg and sperm, there is one thing missing: a human uterus (inside a human woman) in which to grow the resulting embryo.  Without that, you aren't likely to get the embryo to survive.

Additionally, we haven't fully described the structure of the human uterus, nor have we yet created a functional uterine replica.  So, these aliens are out of luck... Unless they are *really* good at simulations and filling in the gaps in the requirements.

Comment: Huh, what sort of knowledge about the uterus is missing? We have been dissecting people for centuries.

Comment: @KeizerHarm We still can't make a replica uterus in which we can gestate a baby.  So, unless these aliens can work out how to build a uterus from the DNA, growing a human isn't going to happen.  Of course, if they can do that, they could just replicate a human...

Answer (score 3):

### Earth 2.0, thank you John (and bravo 2022 scientists)

Q: *"But the brightest minds came together and built a database, containing all of human scientific knowledge as it exists in 2022 AD (the last time anyone had time to do research), and a vast library on culture and arts. They put this gigantic Wikipedia on drives that preserve data indefinitely, made a hundred copies, and put them in rockets that got sent out into space in random directions."*

Don't let other answers worry you, John won't have to reproduce every molecule of us.. we'll just have to resemble the original, to be able to identify with our past.

I don't think copying exactly 1:1 is important. The humans created by John Hammond don't need to be exactly equal. They'll eat similar food, they have the same habits, the same language. To these new people, the Earth photographs should resemble them closely. Languages and writing are copied. The planet should be a plausible Earth, the history of Earth should be a plausible history to teach in schools, as "our" history. No one of the old bunch has survived to check things anyway.

**Your science hard disk is not limited to gene sequences**

Suppose John Hammond would find a suitable planet to host us.

Your space ship's hard disk will have **ALL 2022 data about Earth and humans**, containing genomes, but also an accurate description of the physiology of all known species on earth, with millions of photographs.. 15,000 years of weather data, world maps, history of development. They'd have data about our organ's workings, food requirements, intestinal flora, biochemical formulas covering nearly every enzyme involved in our metabolism.. The hard disk contains detailed information of the atmosphere and nutrients we require.. it contains all medical science. John Hammond  will know the vulnerabilities of Earth's organisms,  which is valuable info to optimize new versions ! Interesting information for creature design !

Social science, psychology, law and government, anthropological science documents, containing knowledge about how humans interact, how we speak, write, how we organize our world.. The database contains philosophical insights, culture.. and it has all technological knowledge developed in 15000 years.

To start with, the alien would be able to reconstruct our shape perfectly, from the photographs. Then, John would put our brain, with the pre-wiring that 2022 science provides. Then, it will take John a century of experiments, to find a healthy way of procreation. John will then attempt to reproduce our traits, from the 2022 culture description and psychological data we provided them with. A world will be terraformed for us, that feeds us and provides us with the resources, so we can develop our second Earth. We will decide the tempo, John Hammond will provide the means for accelerated development when we are ready for it. John is able to reconstruct our 2022 buildings and cities from a detailed world map, the drawings are all present in the database. Our universities are recreated, factories and energy infrastructure and satellite launch facilities.

We are grateful John Hammond evacuated us to Andromeda.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but it seems it would be nearly impossible to bring our species back without any close living relatives that would act as a surrogate mother. And there's the problem of a uterus that could host a human, they could potentially made a superficial uterus. But even with that the odds of these aliens being able to bring back humans seem very slim, as making mammoths has already proved to be very difficult (even with close living relatives) so it really just depends on whether any close relatives still exist. Perhaps a off branch of more primitive humans still exist and could be used as surrogate mothers, sorry if I misunderstood your world.